# 500 internal server error with php class

Tags: php, class, internal-server-error

I have found a new issue with my project using class.

In my `class.php` file contains the following class

```
<?php
    class NEW_CLASS {
        function __construct() {    
            $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Oops connection error -> ' . mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connection) or die('Database error -> ' . mysql_error());
            mysql_set_charset("utf8");
        }
    } 
?>
```

I have access my class with following code in `library.php`

```
<?php 
  include('class.php');
  $object = new NEW_CLASS();
?>
```

In my index file i was included the library file after that i put my codings. In localhost the site works well. But it shows `500 internal server error` in live server.
When i remove the object it works fine. Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Check your logs and check to see if `mysql_` hasn't been deprecated/deleted on the live server.

Comment: Do you get any relevant deprecation errors along with the 500 Internal Server error on PHP? MySQL extension API is deprecated after 5.5.x version: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error means find the real error

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated now, and may have been removed from the server.

Failing that, turn on error reporting in PHP, and the parser will tell you the problem: Update your `library.php` file as follows:

```
<?php 
// Turn on error reporting:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include('class.php');
$object = new NEW_CLASS();
?>
```